# Why use ; after } and })

Tags: java, syntax

UPDATE: Didn't visualize it before but now I can! Thanks! Leaving this question up just in case someone makes the same mistake I do...

ORIGINAL:

I'm pretty rusty in java. I noticed that after instantiating the `View.OnClickListener` object, I had to put a semicolon after `}`. I've also seen semicolons after `})` as well.

Why are there `;` after `}` and `})`?

Here's the code I was looking at:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Because it's a declaration / statement? Why use semi colons after any variables?

Comment: Use Kotlin, no semicolons ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A semicolon is present to mark the end of a statement for the Java compiler, in this case, an object constructor.

The OnClickListener code you have above is an object. That object contains a Declaration, Instantiation, and Initialization. The end of the entire object constructor needs to be established.

Here is an example object constructor.

```java
Example myobj = new Example();
```

Which would look to

```
public Example()
{
    ...
}
```

> More examples and extended information can be found on Oracle's Official Java documentation of [Creating Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Your code is a constructor that has an inline initialization class, instead of calling to an external one like the example above does. Here is an example of your object constructor without the inline initialization class.

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener();
```

Here is your constructor in a single line.

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { ... } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Its there because a new Interface of `View.OnClickListener` was declared inside it the method `okClick` was implemented and in any declaration is followed by a semicolon like declaring a class object for EX

Answer (score 0):

This is Java. And in Java you end statements with semicolon, telling to compiler that is it the end of the statement.

It seems you are confused because of that [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) declaration. In fact, it's just a statement like all other statements.

Check this statement, is there any problem?

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() { myVariable };
```

Now substitute `myVariable` with this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
...
}
```

This is what you get:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
    }
};
```

We could write it in a single line too, but it would be too ugly to read:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){@Override public void onClick(View v) {} };
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you make the declaration. If it's in an execution path, the semicolon declares the end of your statement. This helps the compiler understand how to break apart and interpret your sequence of instructions, given that it expends code to be in a certain format.

If they're defined outside the execution path i.e at the class level, the semicolon is redundant. Again, these are due to selections in the way different structures can be represented in the language.

IDE's are so smart now, that they'll likely recommend to you where the use of a colon is probably redundant. So you can use that as your measuring rod.